# Rewrite requested URL - Apache

Tags: apache, redirect

I am just learning server stuff - my server has a directory like this with a WordPress installation:

```
mydomainname.net/musicflow/
```

I noticed when I just type that line into my browser it loads the page, presumably the index.php script.

I created a new path like this

```
mydomainname.net/QueenAnne/
```

I would like to load the following script when just the above line is typed in a browser:

```
mydomainname.net/QueenAnne/phpinfo.php
```

I looked at the .htaccess file from the musicflow directory and tried to edit it for the QueenAnne page, like this:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /QueenAnne/
RewriteRule ^phpinfo.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /QueenAnne/phpinfo.php [L]`

But it doesn't work, I get a 404 error when I just type the path in my browser. I have documentation for mod_rewrite but I can't seem to understand it's terminology enough to make it work, any help? This is on GoDaddy if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't be easier to create index.php with

```
<?php
header('Location: phpinfo.php');
exit();
?>
```

Comment: What do you know - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webserver_directory_index Didn't know it automatically looks for that. Will award bounty when it lets me.

Comment: Exactly: The Apache's DirectoryIndex directive is responsible for that: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex - but if you haven't access to apache (GoDaddy) - you have to reconcile with that ;D